# Filter PCAP Files by IP using Python

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, tcpdump

My goal is to parse several GB's of PCAP Files to only pull out the ones I need. I am looking to extract packets that use TCP and have either a source or destination address of "11.22.33.44".

I've done some research, but I have not found any successful solutions. Here is what I have (for one file only):

```
# Parses every packet and adds it to an output file. There is NO Filtering
filename = 'C:\\temp\\test.pcap'
ip_addr = "11.22.33.44"
pkts = rdpcap(filename)
filtered = []

for pkt in pkts:
    try:
        filtered.append(pkt)
    except IndexError as e:
        pass
wrpcap('C:\\temp\\filtered.pcap', filtered)
# This code works to save packets from one file to another, but I could not figure out how to use any filters. See below
```

I've seen solutions that suggest using syntax similar to the following using scapy.layers.inet TCP:

```
if pkt[TCP].ipsrc == ip_addr or pkt[TCP].ipdst == ip_addr:
    filtered.append(pkt)
```

But I get an error that pkt[TCP] does not have the attribute, ipsrc.

I've also tried using scapy's sniff() function to read the file, similar to the below code:

```
pkts = sniff(offline='C:\\temp\\test.pcap', filter="ip 11.22.33.44")
print(pkts.nsummary(()))
```

When I run this, I get scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: tcpdump is not available
I do not know how to make tcpdump "available", since I'm running Windows I try using WinDump but the executable seems to be corrupted.

Any advice?

Comment: I think tcpdump is an external tool that you should download and install and add to your PATH. Did you try that already? The github repo of scapy contains at least one [issue](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/2223) mentioning this exact error message. Some tips to improve your question: please add a [mre] (add imports etc. to your code so anybody else can copy-paste and run your code). Also, instead of writing "I get an error", please post the _exact_ error message (stacktrace).

Comment: By the way, it might be better to focus on ONE question at a time. This makes it easier to answer, and more useful for others. "How to use filters" and "how to install tcpdump" are two different questions, with probably different answers/solutions. Maybe you should focus on one question here, and create a second question for the other question.

Comment: alternatively, install/use tshark. Agree with wovano that A) MRE is good B) complete error message is good. Difficult to know where to start with this question, but you may also want to use a capture filter so that the resulting pcap is significantly smaller

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on the scapy side of your question:
You mixed two different layers - the IP address is part of the `IP` layer, and `TCP` layer comes after it (that's why you got the error- the IP address is not part of this layer...).
So in order to get your filter your code should be like:

```
def is_tcp_and_contains_ip_addr(pkt, ip):
    if IP not in pkt or TCP not in pkt:
        return False
    if pkt[IP].src == ip or pkt[IP].dst == ip:
        return True
    return False

ip_addr = "11.22.33.44"
pkts = rdpcap(filename)
filtered = []
for pkt in pkts:
    if is_tcp_and_contains_ip_addr(pkt, ip_addr):
        filtered.append(pkt)
```